# Running into issues using CloudRun and running pubsub subscriber

Tags: google-cloud-run

I am trying to use CloudRun to run my node.js code which has a pubsub client subscriber set for pull mode.

This code works fine on my local machine, but in cloudrun..it stops processing after a certain amount of time.

I updated the cloudrun instance to not scale below 1 minimum instance...and I thought this would ensure the cloudrun instance would stay active, and therefore the subscriber would continue to work..but that is not the case..

Is it not possible to use CloudRun for this type of use-case? Do I need to deploy my container to Google Compute? I was hoping to keep everything on cloudrun if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just realized easier solution is to setup Push Subscriber, which I can use cloudrun for. This solves the issue